# Opening file from sd card using dmenu

Tags: files, directory-structure

I would like to use dmenu to open files. I figured out how to get this to work if the file is in my home directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE="workbook.pdf"

zathura "$FILE"
```

However, I cannot get it to work with files from my sd card. I tried:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE="mnt/School/Latin/Lingua\ Latina/Workbook/workbook.pdf"

zathura "$FILE"
```

This opens Zathura, but not the pdf. I tried other pdf files, too, but they would not open. I tried having the backslash (to represent a space) and not having it. I tried

```
zathura "mnt/School/Latin/Lingua\ Latina/Workbook/workbook.pdf"
```

with and without a "$" after the first quotation mark. In short, I've tried just about everything I can think of. I can't find any examples of people using dmenu to open files, let alone open them from another partition.

Any help would be appreciated (including finding a different way to quickly open these files). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one slash at the beginning, the path should start with:

```
/mnt/...
```

instead of

```
mnt/...
```

It is formally called the *root directory* and with it (`/`) every full path begins. [More info here](https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/the-root-directory.html) for example.